# How to color only for points above and below certain amounts in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a reproducible code below, I only want to color the points below and above the dotted black lines and nothing in between. The points in between should be grey or whatever default color without aes(color = x)

```
color_above <- mean(iris$Sepal.Width) + sd(iris$Sepal.Width)
color_below <- mean(iris$Sepal.Width) - sd(iris$Sepal.Width)


ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +  ylab("Sepal Width")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = color_above, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = color_below, linetype = "dashed", color = "black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to add a column to your dataframe where using an `ifelse` assigns an `NA` to obs. between your threshold lines and map this new column on the `color` aes. These values will automatically be assigned the `na.value` of `scale_color_discrete`. To get rid of the `NA` entry in the legend I use the `breaks` argument and set the `name` for the color legend to `Species` so that it still gets merged with the `shape` legend.

```r
library(ggplot2)

color_above <- mean(iris$Sepal.Width) + sd(iris$Sepal.Width)
color_below <- mean(iris$Sepal.Width) - sd(iris$Sepal.Width)

iris$color <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width > color_above | iris$Sepal.Width < color_below, as.character(iris$Species), NA_character_)

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = color)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=Species)) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = unique(iris$Species), name = "Species") +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +
  ylab("Sepal Width")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = color_above, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = color_below, linetype = "dashed", color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: I started going down the road of explicitly controlling the color (`scale_color_manual`), but the use of `NA` to get `ggplot2`'s implicit gray is so much better! (I will need to incorporate `na.value` into my habit-pattern/workflow now.)

Comment: @r2evans Haha. That was my first thought too. (: Already started with using `cut` to get the categories for `scale_color_manual`  ... before I realized that we could do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a new layer:

```
grey <- iris[iris$Sepal.Width < color_above & iris$Sepal.Width > color_below,]

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
  xlab("Sepal Length") +  ylab("Sepal Width")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = color_above, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = color_below, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +
  geom_point(data=grey,aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width),color='grey')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `gghighlight` package: I think this made for such situations:

```
p +  gghighlight::gghighlight(Sepal.Width > 3.5 | Sepal.Width < 2.6)
```

[image]